# After upgrading to Python 3.5.2 urllib is returning extra characters

Tags: python, urllib

I had to upgrade to python 3.5.2 to meet the requirements for another application. After I did I started having trouble with urllib results. The below code is returning "b'0'" but the 2.7 version returned just "0". How do I go back to just getting "0"?

Here is my code:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://blockexplorer.com/api/addr/19hMEAaRMbEhfSkeU4GT8mgSuyR4t4M6TH/balance') as req:
                balance = req.read()
print(balance)
```

Comment: `b'0'` is a `bytes` object. You can use [`decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) to convert it to a string.

Comment: Thank you that did the trick!